# Не правильно строится маршрут яндекс карта (api)

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Я строю маршрут с использованием путевых и транзитных точек. Но яндекс карта не правильно строит маршрут. Она соединяется там где не должна.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот ссылка на [codepen](https://codepen.io/zilermand/pen/MGVEwb) и код:

```js
function init() {

  var multiRoute = [];

  function createMultiRoute(routeData, viaData, color) {
    multiRoute.push( new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
        referencePoints: routeData,
        params: viaData
      }, {
        editorDrawOver: false,
        wayPointDraggable: true,
        viaPointDraggable: true,
        routeStrokeColor: "000088",
        routeActiveStrokeColor: color,
        pinIconFillColor: color,
        boundsAutoApply: true,
        zoomMargin: 30
    }));
  }

  // Создаем карту с добавленными на нее кнопками.
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.750625, 37.626],
    zoom: 14
  });

  createMultiRoute([
        [60.014919, 30.649850],
        [60.014958, 30.648536],
        [60.017671, 30.646447],
        [60.019146, 30.645540],
        [60.024197, 30.645711],
        [60.025782, 30.644554],
        [60.028975, 30.640299],
        [60.027754, 30.630244],
        [60.024331, 30.631359],
        [60.023627, 30.637576],
        [60.023723, 30.638850],
        [60.024200, 30.645713]
      ], {
      viaIndexes: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
      }, "ff0000");

    myMap.geoObjects.add(multiRoute[0]);

}

ymaps.ready(init);
```

```css
#map {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы не было подобных соединений?

Comment: вероятно, где-то в вашем коде ошибка. соберите минимальный пример кода, на котором можно увидеть проблему.

Comment: Вот Ссылка на codepen https://codepen.io/zilermand/pen/MGVEwb

Comment: Может у вас там по Плоткина одностороннее движение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Может у вас там по Плоткина одностороннее движение?

Точнее, на неё нет поворота с перекрёстка.

Маршрут построен правильно, чтобы пройти по точкам, приходится делать круг..

[Более простой маршрут](https://yandex.ru/maps/10865/vsevolgsk/?mode=routes&ol=geo&ouri=ymapsbm1%3A%2F%2Fgeo%3Fll%3D30.633%252C60.023%26spn%3D0.025%252C0.003%26text%3D%25D0%25A0%25D0%25BE%25D1%2581%25D1%2581%25D0%25B8%25D1%258F%252C%2520%25D0%259B%25D0%25B5%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B8%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B3%25D1%2580%25D0%25B0%25D0%25B4%25D1%2581%25D0%25BA%25D0%25B0%25D1%258F%2520%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B1%25D0%25BB%25D0%25B0%25D1%2581%25D1%2582%25D1%258C%252C%2520%25D0%2592%25D1%2581%25D0%25B5%25D0%25B2%25D0%25BE%25D0%25BB%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B6%25D1%2581%25D0%25BA%252C%2520%25D1%2583%25D0%25BB%25D0%25B8%25D1%2586%25D0%25B0%2520%25D0%259F%25D0%25BB%25D0%25BE%25D1%2582%25D0%25BA%25D0%25B8%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B0%2520&ll=30.635765%2C60.024800&z=16&rtext=60.023302%2C30.631645~60.023155%2C30.632211&rtt=auto)

[Знак на gmaps](https://www.google.com/maps/@60.0233432,30.6316627,3a,75y,206.45h,84.86t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sc9i4QGEwpR04JJQLnrYXtw!2e0!7i13312!8i6656)

Comment: Вполне вероятно, что может быть одностороннее движение. В любом случае спасибо :)

Comment: Как я могу забыть сделать такую важную вещь?

Comment: Я сейчас перестроил маршрут и все заработало. Я действительно не учел что может быть одностороннее движение)) Еще раз спасибо.